# What the intense plucky guitar song that begins at 3:35 in My Hero Acadamia Season 3 ep 62/24

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

I can't seem to find the song. It's on Episode 24 of season 3 or ep. 62. It starts at 3:35 and its a really nice and mysterious guitar melody!

Answer (score 2):

Its "People Always Reaching for the Top" from the 2nd OST :)